# Marriage visitor visa refusal

Tags: uk, visa-refusals

My marriage visitor visa was refused on the basis of a document which was tagged non genuine (offer letter from a registered company)

We are considering filing a pre action protocol explaining our situation and proving that the document is true and genuine and get a response from Home office.

1. Any advice on filing pre action protocol? We didn't find any good lawyers yet, still searching as most of them we spoke to don't seem professional.
2. We are also considering getting married in another country and applying for EEA family permit, will previous U.K. Visa refusal affect my application for EEA, even when we're husband an wife?

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: Things are uncertain at the moment, but the plan still is that the UK leaves the EU at the end of March. It's far from given that they will care about EEA permits after that.

Comment: @Pri95 What is your future husband’s citizenship?

Comment: He's from Cyprus and been working in the UK for nearly 4 years

Comment: @Pri95 This may help if you’ve not already read it https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/763556/jr-guidance-england-wales-v1.0ext.pdf

Comment: Thanks! We are in the process of hiring a lawyer, spoke to one today, probably finalise on that, but would getting married and getting an EEA permit have a better chance? End of the day my fiancé and I just want to be together, and our families are happy to get us married.